How to debug a powerShell script using Visual Studio Code that is called from a external process (app)
I create a service application that is running on my server, that app is (called) running a PowerShell script if some conditions are selected by the user.
Im able to debug the script from the Visual Studio Code app using the plugin and Debug command(F5), also Im able to go step by step (F10-F11) and see and watch variables. My script creates a log file.
My issue is when I run from the service app, my script is not saving the log file. THen probably some variable is not correct, but I dont know which one.
Is there any way to attach the service app and when the service app executes the script be able to debug using Visual Studio Code or similar?
I try to use launch.json but look that do not work
"configurations": [ { "name": "PowerShell Attach to Service", "type": "PowerShell", "request": "attach", "processId": "MyService.exe", "runspaceId": 1 } ]
